# Using Facebook login token from Android device with passport-facebook

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the scenario

The user logs in using "Login with facebook" (set up with Facebook SDK) from his android device

I know have with me the access token.

On the server side (in NodeJS) I have implemented passport-facebook (mainly for use with the web application).

My question is - Is there any way to use the access token received on the android app (sent over to the server through a REST API) to authenticate the user through passport-facebook.

If no, what would be the best way to save the user's credentials on the database in the server?

Thank you in advance for your time